# what i'm supposed to do to make flexible URLs for any type of files?

Tags: java, embedded-resource

Is there any way to make flexible URL'S for some files? 
I have a program that plays a sound and I want to run it on other computers.
How can I make my program finds the specific sound file?
Or maybe I want to make a flexible  URL for text files or something.
Can someone provide me with a code-example for this?
Or should I ask the user using  `JFileChooser`?

Or maybe I should attach the file with my program? Is this possible?

P.S:
Explained code-examples would be better because I'm not an expert.

edit: the sound file is inside the project folder(using eclipse)
so it should be in some place like this
C:\Users\Rev3rse\workspace\Project1\someSound.mp3
i hope i gave u enough info...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "flexible URLs" in this context. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Is it always in the same place ? Because then you can just give the relative path : /somedir/mysound.file, where the top dir is the dir where you program is ran from.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make flexible URL'S for some files? 
>   ..maybe I should attach the file with my program? Is this possible?

It is not only possible, but commonly done.  Package the resources in a Jar.  For documents, you might use standard Zip(/Jar) compression.  It does not make much sense to use that type of compression with images or sound files, which typically have their own (very efficient) forms of compression.  Add the Jar to the application's run-time class-path.

To get an URL to the resource, simply use something along the lines of:

```
URL urlToResource = this.getClass().getResource("path/to/the.resource");
```

..where `path/to/` is the sub-directory of the Jar in which `the.resource` is located.

Comment: can u give me example without path/to/the.resource, im talking about real URL can u please?

Comment: @Rev3rse: *"im talking about real URL "* What does [Class.getResource(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) **really** return according to the JavaDocs that you get when you click that link?  What happened when you tried *using* that method?

Comment: when i try getClass.getResource, the returned value is "null" did i do it the wrong way or what? check this :URL url = this.getClass().getResource(someSound.mp3);.. i tried almost all possible path's too..

Comment: Where is `someSound.mp3`?  Is it in the same directory as the Jar files?  Is it in a Jar on the run-time class-path?  You are not giving me enough information to go no.  Please update your question with much more detail.  This technique requires the resource to be in the right place - it does not work by magic.